# How do I get the impressions counter from Twitter using tweepy python-twitter-api?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

How to I get the impressions counter from twitter using python-twitter-api?

This is my code, so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                                                                                               
from pyquery import PyQuery
import datetime

from operator import add
import numpy as np
import tweepy
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth

CONSUMER_KEY = '***'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '***'
ACCESS_TOKEN = '***'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '***'

twitter = Twitter(auth=OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = twitter.Api()
```

Comment: There is no free Twitter API for impressions so this will not work for you.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think there it is possible with curl or something?

Comment: It is possible using the Twitter Engagement API, but that is a commercial offering with an annual subscription. It also works only for accounts that you have credentials / OAuth secrets for.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, for this information. This was really confusing before.